# Autofac Component Circular Dependency in C# Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac, circular-dependency

I want to implement Autofac for my PurchasesController(). Like my other controllers i've registered the dependencies into Global.asax. And it's working as expected. But for PurchasesController() component circular dependency exception is happening for FiscalYearManager. To mention everything works fine if i don't use Autofac for this controller. I've put the screenshot of that error and uploaded necessary codes related to this. Please review and help me solve this. 
[image]

**Global.asax -> Application_Start()**

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // MVC - Register Controllers
        builder.RegisterType<ProductsController>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<PurchasesController>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SalesController>().InstancePerRequest();

        // MVC - OPTIONAL: Register model binders that require DI.
        builder.RegisterModelBinders(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterModelBinderProvider();

        // MVC - OPTIONAL: Register web abstractions like HttpContextBase.
        builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();

        // MVC - OPTIONAL: Enable property injection in view pages.
        builder.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());

        // MVC - OPTIONAL: Enable property injection into action filters.
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
// Register application dependencies for PurchaseController
        builder.RegisterType<PurchaseManager>().As<IPurchaseManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<GeneralInventoryManager>().As<IGeneralInventoryManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceCenterInventoryManager>().As<IServiceCenterInventoryManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PurchaseBatchPaymentManager>().As<IPurchaseBatchPaymentManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PartyManager>().As<IPartyManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PurchaseFileManager>().As<IPurchaseFileManager>();            
        builder.RegisterType<ProductCategoryManager>().As<IProductCategoryManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PosPurchaseFileManager>().As<IPosPurchaseFileManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PosPurchasePaymentManager>().As<IPosPurchasePaymentManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<CategoryManager>().As<ICategoryManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<ItemManager>().As<IItemManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<PurchaseOrderManager>().As<IPurchaseOrderManager>();
        builder.RegisterType<FiscalYearManager>().As<IFiscalYearManager>().SingleInstance()
        .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

**PurchasesController()**

```
private readonly LoaderUtility _loaderUtility;
    private readonly IPurchaseManager _iManager;
    private readonly IGeneralInventoryManager _iGeneralInventoryManager;
    private readonly IServiceCenterInventoryManager _iServiceCenterInventoryManager;
    private readonly IPurchaseBatchPaymentManager _iPurchaseBatchPaymentManager;
    private readonly IPartyManager _iPartyManager;
    private readonly IPurchaseFileManager _iPurchaseFileManager;
    private readonly IFiscalYearManager _iFiscalYearManager;
    private readonly IProductCategoryManager _iProductCategoryManager;
    private readonly IPosPurchaseFileManager _iPosPurchaseFileManager;
    private readonly IPosPurchasePaymentManager _iPosPurchasePaymentManager;
    private readonly ICategoryManager _iCategoryManager;
    private readonly IItemManager _iItemManager;
    private readonly IPurchaseOrderManager _iPurchaseOrderManager;


    public PurchasesController(IItemManager itemManager,
        LoaderUtility loaderUtility,
        IPurchaseManager purchaseManager,
        IGeneralInventoryManager iGeneralInventoryManager,
        IServiceCenterInventoryManager iServiceCenterInventoryManager,
        IPurchaseBatchPaymentManager iPurchaseBatchPaymentManager,
        IPartyManager iPartyManager, 
        IFiscalYearManager iFiscalYearManager,
        IProductCategoryManager iProductCategoryManager,
        IPosPurchaseFileManager iPosPurchaseFileManager,
        IPosPurchasePaymentManager iPosPurchasePaymentManager,
        ICategoryManager iCategoryManager,
        IPurchaseOrderManager purchaseOrderManager
        )
    {
        _loaderUtility = loaderUtility;
        _iManager = purchaseManager;
        _iGeneralInventoryManager = iGeneralInventoryManager;
        _iPurchaseBatchPaymentManager = iPurchaseBatchPaymentManager;
        _iPartyManager = iPartyManager;
        _iFiscalYearManager = iFiscalYearManager;
        _iItemManager = itemManager;
        _iProductCategoryManager = iProductCategoryManager;
        _iPosPurchaseFileManager = iPosPurchaseFileManager;
        _iPosPurchasePaymentManager = iPosPurchasePaymentManager;
        _iCategoryManager = iCategoryManager;
        _iPurchaseOrderManager = purchaseOrderManager;
        _iServiceCenterInventoryManager = iServiceCenterInventoryManager;
    }
```

**PurchasesManager()**

```
private readonly IPurchaseRepository _iRepository;
    private readonly IVatConfManager _iVatConfManager;
    private readonly ITaxConfManager _iTaxConfManager;
    private readonly IInventoryAccountConfRepository _inventoryAccountConfRepository;
    private readonly IPosPurchasePaymentManager _iPosPurchasePaymentManager;
    private readonly IPurchaseDetailsManager _iPurchaseDetailsManager;
    private readonly IGeneralInventoryManager _iInventoryManager;
    private readonly IServiceCenterInventoryManager _iServiceCenterInventoryManager;
    private readonly IVoucherManager _iVoucherManager;
    private readonly IJournalCategoryManager _iJournalCategoryManager;
    private readonly ICategoryRepository _iCategoryRepository;
    private readonly IFiscalYearManager _iFiscalYearManager;
    private readonly PosVoucherGenerateManager _voucherGenerateManager;

    public PurchaseManager()
    {
        _iRepository = new PurchaseRepository();
        _iVatConfManager = new VatConfigurationManager();
        _iTaxConfManager = new TaxConfigurationManager();
        _inventoryAccountConfRepository = new InventoryAccountConfRepository();
        _iFiscalYearManager = new FiscalYearManager();
        _iCategoryRepository = new CategoryRepository();
        _iJournalCategoryManager = new JournalCategoryManager();
        _iPosPurchasePaymentManager = new PosPurchasePaymentManager();
        _iInventoryManager = new GeneralInventoryManager();
        _iServiceCenterInventoryManager = new ServiceCenterInventoryManager();
        _iPurchaseDetailsManager = new PurchaseDetailsManager();
        _iVoucherManager = new VoucherManager();
        _voucherGenerateManager = new PosVoucherGenerateManager();

    }

    public PurchaseManager(IPurchaseRepository iReporitory,
        IGeneralInventoryManager inventoryManager,
        IServiceCenterInventoryManager serviceCentreInventoryManager,
        IPurchaseDetailsManager iPurchaseDetailsManager,
        IPosPurchasePaymentManager iPosPurchasePaymentManager,
        IJournalCategoryManager iJournalCategoryManager,
        ICategoryRepository iCategoryRepository,
        IVatConfManager iVatConfManager,
        ITaxConfManager iTaxConfManager,
        IFiscalYearManager iFiscalYearManager,
        IPurchaseBatchPaymentManager iBatchPaymentManager)
    {
        this._iRepository = iReporitory;
        _iVatConfManager = iVatConfManager;
        _iTaxConfManager = iTaxConfManager;
        this._iInventoryManager = inventoryManager;
        this._iServiceCenterInventoryManager = serviceCentreInventoryManager;
        _iPurchaseDetailsManager = iPurchaseDetailsManager;
        _iPosPurchasePaymentManager = iPosPurchasePaymentManager;
        _iJournalCategoryManager = iJournalCategoryManager;
        _iCategoryRepository = iCategoryRepository;
        _iFiscalYearManager = iFiscalYearManager;
    }
```

**IFiscalYearManager()**

```
public interface IFiscalYearManager : IManager<FiscalYear>
{
    ICollection<FiscalYear> Search(FiscalYearSearchVm model);
    bool CheckFiscalYear(FiscalYear entity);
    FiscalYear GetCurrentFiscalYear();
    bool IsDateInFiscalYear(DateTime? date);
}
```

Comment: please share the ER diagram which is only related to FiscalYear

Comment: Please don't post [images of exceptions](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), but post the full exception details with stack trace in text instead.

Comment: But as the Autofac exception mentions, `FiscalYear` takes a dependency on the controller making the dependency cyclic. The source of the problem seems the massive Single Responsibility Principle violation going on in your code. Typically, cyclic dependencies can be prevented by making your classes smaller, more focussed.